# Proof that if $p \prec q$ then $\|p\|_a \le \|q\|_a$ for all $a \ge 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Could somebody please direct me to a proof that if $p \prec q$ then $\|p\|_a \le \|q\|_a$ for all $a \ge 1$?

We have $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\|x\|_a = (\sum_i{x_i^a})^{\frac{1}{a}}$ and $p \prec q$ means the majorization order:

$$\sum_i^{k}{p_i}^{\downarrow} \le \sum_i^{k}{q_i}^{\downarrow},\text{ for }k = 1,\dots, n-1$$

$$\sum_i{p_i}^{\downarrow} = \sum_i{q_i}^{\downarrow}$$

Moreover I have that particularly $\sum_i{p_i} = \sum_i{q_i} = 1$ and $0\le q_i \le 1$ and $0\le p_i \le 1$ $\forall i$, although I believe this doesn't really matter.

Extra question: Would the statement hold if $a \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this paper.](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/techreports/NSF/OLK%20NSF%20172.pdf) Your result follows immediately from Theorem 2.3 (and convexity of the $L^p$ norms), but you might want to read the rest of the paper, too.

Comment: Can theorem 2.2 along with the identity $||Bx||_a\leq ||B||_a||q||_a$ will also be a solution. (Here $B$ is the doubly stochastic matrix, thus $||B||_a\leq ||B||_1\leq1$).

Comment: Igor Rivin and dineshdileep, thank you both for your answers!

Comment: @dineshdileep Good point!